# Folders are not excluded from vs code search

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to exclude some folders from search. I've added folders to exclude in both *User* and *Workspace* settings, but I'm still getting results from these folders. *vs code* version is `1.30.2`, *Windows 10*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [search options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options):

> Also note the Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files toggle button in
>   the files to exclude box. The toggle determines whether to exclude
>   files that are ignored by your .gitignore files and/or matched by your
>   files.exclude and search.exclude settings.

From your screenshot it does not look like the toggle button is set to "Use Exclude Settings..."  Toggle that to on and see if your exclude settings work.  Highlighted in the gif and already turned on (note the blue focus box surrounding it):

[image: demo gif of toggle button location]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGRoC.png)

files exclude cannot work when search. You should config in the search exclude